# adobe flex embede font don't show in the Text tag

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" paddingTop="0" paddingLeft="0" paddingBottom="0" paddingRight="0">

    <mx:Style>
        .top
        {

            backgroundColor: #562d67;
        }
        .profile
        {
            color: white;

        }
        .profile_1
        {
            backgroundColor: red;

        }
        @font-face
        {
            src: url("ObelixProB-cyr.ttf");
            fontFamily: obelix;
            advancedAntiAliasing: true;
        }
        @font-face
        {
            src: url("BRLNSB.ttf");
            fontFamily: brlnsb;
            advancedAntiAliasing: true;
        }
    </mx:Style>
    <mx:Box styleName="top" width="1451" height="132">
        <mx:Image id="logo" source="@Embed(source='logo.png')"/>

        <mx:Box styleName="profile" verticalAlign="middle">
            <mx:Text width="100" fontFamily="obelix">
                <mx:htmlText>
                    <![CDATA[<strong>some text here</strong>]]>
                </mx:htmlText>
            </mx:Text>
        </mx:Box>

    </mx:Box>

</mx:Application>
```

I've embeded some fonts, but when I use it in the `<mx:Text>` it doesn't work, it just don't show anything

in the other script I've used this to check if the font is loaded:

```
Application.application.systemManager.
           isFontFaceEmbedded(tf2);
```

and it return true, there are no errors in the console, but it just don't show the text...what can be the reason of that?

Comment: Try adding `embedAsCFF: true;` to the `@font-face` tags. I had similar issues on my last project and embedding as CFF fixed them. That was using Spark and not MX, though

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use your code. It worked gut, but I had to add one more line in style definition "fontWeight: bold;". Without this line I got an error. If you use a normal version of the font, write "fontWeight: normal;" instead.

[image]

```
<mx:Style>
    @font-face
    {
        src:url("/assets/font/ObelixPro-cyr.ttf");
        fontFamily: obelix;
        fontWeight: bold;
        advancedAntiAliasing: true;
    }
</mx:Style>
```

Another possible problem can be with the font file, which you use.
I found my font [here](http://www.maxfonts.com/fonts/o/obelix-pro.font).